# How to use TouchID in sirikit

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

Am exploring sirikit with touch ID in my app for payment. In the function handle i called the touch ID function but i'm getting blank black screen in siri UI can anyone help me if there is some way to do this.

```
func handle(intent: INSendPaymentIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendPaymentIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        guard let payee = intent.payee, let amount = intent.currencyAmount else {
        return completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .unspecified, userActivity: nil))
        }
            LAContext().evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: "Allow siri to do the Payment", reply:
               {(accessGranted:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
                   if (accessGranted){
                       print("Sending \(amount) payment to \(payee)!")
                        completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
                    }
           })
        print("Sending \(amount) payment to \(payee)!")
        completion(INSendPaymentIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
    }
```